# How much does buying all the cards cost?

Tags: gwent

I know there are two currencies you can buy cards with: Scraps [image], and Meteorite Powder [image]. But how much would it cost to buy all the cards in the game?

By all cards I mean:

- Three of all Bronze cards.
- One of each Silver card.
- One of each Gold card.
- Both Premium and Standard cards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>Last checked against the May 24th, 2017 patch</sub>

The prices for each card looks pretty static, and are based off the cards *Rarity*. **Bronze** cards can be either **Common** or **Rare** rarities, where **Silvers** are **Epic**, and **Golds** are **Legendary**. When buying with Scraps[image] you can buy either the Standard version or the Premium version. However when you're using Meteorite Powder[image], you have to have a Standard version of a card to Transmute to the Premium version, consuming the Standard version in the process. The price for these are:

- Common: 30 / 200 [image: Scraps] or 100[image: Meteorite Powder]
- Rare: 80 / 400 [image: Scraps] or 200[image: Meteorite Powder]
- Epic: 200 / 800 [image: Scraps] or 300[image: Meteorite Powder]
- Legendary: 800 / 1,600 [image: Scraps] or 400[image: Meteorite Powder]

---

In total there are: 66 Common cards, 67 Rare cards, 103 Epic cards, and 81 Legendary cards. And so using the following price formula:

Price = (*Common* * 66 * 3) + (*Rare* * 67 * 3) + (*Epic* * 103) + (*Legendary* * 81)

The prices are (this doesn't exclude default cards):

- All Standard cards: 107,420[image: Scraps]
- All Premium cards: 332,000[image: Scraps] or 107,420[image: Scraps] + 123,300[image: Meteorite Powder]
- All cards: 439,420[image: Scraps] or 214,840[image: Scraps] + 123,300[image: Meteorite Powder]

---

To find out how many of each group there are, enter your collection and apply the filters you want. Afterwards exit the filter screen to enter the normal collection screen. Where it should then tell you how many of each faction you have, and how many there are in total. For example, say you filter for all Premium Legendary cards, the left hand side will tell us there are 81 Legendary cards across all factions, where only 19 of them are Neutral cards.